# Tag feature with browser tests (Cucumber JUnit Platform Engine)

Tags: junit, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have several API tests, and browser tests. Browser tests must run consistently.
This documentation (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine) says:

1. first, I need to run all tests in parallel using the following parameters:

```
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=4
```

2. then I need mark the resources, access to which will be consistent (read and write, or read only). For example, the resource SYSTEM_PROPERTIES:

```
cucumber.execution.exclusive-resources.reads-and-writes-system-properties.read-write=SYSTEM_PROPERTIES
```

**But, how can I specify my browser tests instead of this resource?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your exclusive resource is the browser you mentally reserve the string `BROWSER` for it. It doesn't really matter what you name the resource, just that it is uniquely identifies the browser.

Then you decide which Cucumber tag matches this resource, say `@browser`. Then you remove the `@` from the tag and put the remainder in the properties file:

```
cucumber.execution.exclusive-resources.browser.read-write=BROWSER
```

Then you tag your scenario with `@browser`:

```
Feature: Exclusive resources

 @browser
 Scenario: first example
   Given this scenario uses the browser

 @browser
 Scenario: second example
   Given this scenario uses the browser
```

You can also tag all scenarios in feature by tagging the feature

```
@browser
Feature: Exclusive resources

 Scenario: first example
   Given this scenario uses the browser

 Scenario: second example
   Given this scenario uses the browser
```